# MYSQL: How to update uuid in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql-update, foreign-keys, hierarchy, guid

I have 2 tables:

```
table1
-UUID Id
-CHAR NAME

table2
-UUID Id
-UUID table1Id (foreign key for table1 Id)
-CHAR CHILD_INFO
```

I need to update these 2 tables Ids to new UUID. (For some copy reason) 
How to do this with one update (1) Change talbe1 Id to new, 2) change this foreign id in talbe2 table1Id?
P.S. we can't use cascade in foreign constraints because somewhere use polymorphic relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found resolution of this problem with query like this:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

UPDATE table1 as t1
join (select uuid() as newId, Id from table1) as ut1 on t1.Id = ut1.Id
LEFT join table2 as t2 on t1.Id = t2.table1Id
SET t1.Id = ut1.newId, t2.table1Id = ut1.newId;

SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

So you need to join child tables with Left Join and do that complex update.